# VBA Script to Combine Duplicate Data into One Row

Tags: vba, sorting, row

I'm attempting to write a script to, given a list of parts and their used-on numbers, combine the used-on values for all duplicate parts and sort the resulting values. That sounded confusing so here is an image of what I'm shooting for:

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuV83.jpg)

It should be able to handle duplicates and blanks.

Through a combination of research and tinkering, I've gotten a `sortWithinCell` function made, but my headaches are coming from writing the script to iterate down the list of parts, combining used-on values as you go, and then upon reaching a different part number, delete all but the first row that you started from and then continue. Assume that the input parts list is already sorted by part number.

Thanks all!

-Edit 1-

I did manage to find a way to combine the data values:

Function ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange(sourceRange As Excel.Range) As String
    Dim finalValue As String

```
Dim cell As Excel.Range

For Each cell In sourceRange.Cells
    finalValue = finalValue + "," + CStr(cell.Value)
Next cell

ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange = Right(finalValue, Len(finalValue) - 1)
```

End Function

However, now the trick is still identifying the input range for this function, i.e. when the part number changes.

Answer (score 0):

A possibile solution would be to create a collection which uses the Part as Key and has the Used-On values as value, so at the first occurence of Part, the KeyValue pair is added, then in an ongoing loop, if the key already exists in the collection, take the value of the key and the one from the collection, merge them together, delete the current KeyValue pair and add a new one (You can't modify a KeyValue pair of a collection, therefore delete the old one and add a new one).

If you are finished looping through your list, you can loop through the elements in the collection and save them somewhere else on the sheet. Or if you want, delete the current range and insert everything where the old values were.

Let me know if you need help with this

---

**EDIT**

Here is an example of the method I described, though i used a Dictionary instead of a Collection, because it has more functionality (REQUIRES A REFERENCE TO "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"):

```
Option Explicit

Sub combineStuff()

    'Create Dictionary
    Dim tmpDic As New Dictionary

    'tempstring to preserve the value of a key
    Dim tmpValue As String


    Dim i As Integer

    'Loop through rows - change this to your needs
    For i = 1 To 15 Step 1

        'Simple check if "Part" and "Used-On" are both filled
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then

            'Check if the Key already exists
            If tmpDic.Exists(CStr(Cells(i, 1).Value)) Then

                'If it does, save it's value
                tmpValue = tmpDic.Item(CStr(Cells(i, 1).Value))

                'Delete the Key Value pair
                tmpDic.Remove CStr(Cells(i, 1).Value)

                'Add Key Value pair with updated Value
                tmpDic.Add CStr(Cells(i, 1).Value), tmpValue & "," & CStr(Cells(i, 2).Value)
            Else

                'Key does not exist yet, add it
                tmpDic.Add CStr(Cells(i, 1).Value), Cells(i, 2).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    Dim tmpKey As Variant
    i = 1

    'Loop through all items in the Dictionary
    For Each tmpKey In tmpDic

        'Insert Key
        Cells(i, 4).Value = tmpKey

        'Insert Value
        Cells(i, 5).Value = tmpDic(tmpKey)
        i = i + 1
    Next tmpKey

End Sub
```

Note that the Dictionary will not be sorted! The key that was modified last is the last one in the list. If you want the outcome to be sorted, it might be better to use a multidimensional array to store the key and value pairs. Then you can easily sort those.

Comment: That sounds like it would definitely work - unfortunately I'm not as practiced with VBA as I would like and I'm not sure how I'd do that. I would definitely appreciate the help!

Comment: How do you go about referencing the Microsoft Scripting Runtime? @gizlmeier

Comment: So your solution works perfectly except for part 333:

111 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
222 10,20,30,15,20,30
333 100200, ,1,5,10,66125

I'd imagine the blank for one of the Part 333 entries might be messing with the procedure... I'm trying to debug now

Comment: For whatever reason, wherever "100,200" and "66,125" is in the list, the generated list removes the comma... I've played around with it and can't figure out why. It works for other number combinations..

Comment: I have no idea why this happens